# Is a GKE Ingress sufficient as a proxy for gunicorn?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gunicorn

I am running a Python application behind Gunicorn in a container in GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine). The application sits behind a GKE Ingress, i.e., an HTTP(S) Load Balancer. The Gunicorn documentation says

> We strongly recommend using Gunicorn behind a proxy server.

The documentation goes on to say they recommend using Nginx for the proxy server.

My question is: given that my application already sits behind an HTTP(S) Load Balancer is there anything to be gained by adding an extra Nginx layer?